# Retain url hash parameters when changing pages internally

Tags: javascript

I want the following link to retain its hash parameters when changing pages:

mysite.com/register.html#referral_code=2061710

so when I change to this page for example:

mysite.com/prices.html

it ends up being:

mysite.com/prices.html#referral_code=2061710

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the code with javascript.

```
 var code = window.location.search;
 for (var el of document.querySelectorAll("a")) {
   if (el.href.indexOf("mysite.com") >= 0) { // Validate url
     el.href += code;
   }
 }
```

Use `window.location.search` if your url is like `something?referral=xxx`. If your url is like `something#referral=xxx` use:

```
 var url = window.location.url;
 var code = url.substr(url.indexOf("#"));
```